Paragraph textContent disappear after flashing its value momentarily
I am learning how to handle files with multer, to do this i wrote a simple code that takes the uploaded file, parse it to an api that retrieves the the data from the text file and returns the said data, after that i simple modify the paragraph's text content to be this data from the file.
The problem is that text content flashes for a moment and then the page returns to its prior form. I reckon the web page refreshes after the form submission despite me adding preventDefault();
Please help me understand what i did wrong.
I am a beginner so go easy on me if i made a silly mistake.
I am attaching coding from all the files below:
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FILE HANDLING</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload a file below</h1>
    <!-- action="http://localhost:3000/upload" -->
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FileSubmitForm">
        <label for="FileInput">Upload a file: </label>
        <input type="file" id="FileInput" name="file" required>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
    <p id="displayContent">To be changed</p>
    <script src="file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

file.js:
document.getElementById("FileSubmitForm").addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submission prevented");
    // event.stopPropagation();

    const fileInput = document.getElementById("FileInput");
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/upload', {
        method: 'POST', 
        body: formData
    })
        .then((response)=>response.json())
        .then((data)=>{
            console.log("success, server response:");
            console.log(data)
            console.log("This is what we are changing the content with");
            let newText = data.result;
            console.log(newText);
            document.getElementById('displayContent').textContent = newText;
            // document.getElementById('displayContent').style.display = 'block';
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.error("Error", err);
        });
});

apifile.js:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

// if(!fs.existsSync('./uploads')){
//     fs.mkdir('./uploads');
// }

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }); // Configure multer to store files in the 'uploads' directory

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;
    console.log(req.file);
    if (!file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ result: 'No file uploaded' });
    }

    // Read the file contents
    fs.readFile(file.path, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ result: 'Error reading file' });
        }
        
        res.status(200).json({ result: data });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('API is running on http://localhost:3000');
});


I tried using preventDefault() but it doesn't work

Your code is absolutely fine. My guess is that you're using some live reload extension in your code editor. When your file is uploaded, this extension in your code editor is detecting file changes in your working directory and triggering a reload of your HTML page.
To verify this, open html file directly in browser without any reload extension. If this is true, then add your uploads directory path in the watch ignore list of that extension settings.
